# What is a simplicial graph?

Tags: graph-theory, definition, geometric-group-theory

I keep seeing the term "simplicial graph" thrown around in the context of geometric group theory. I assume this means a graph which is also a simplicial complex (a graph with no loops), but I am having trouble finding a good source that explicitly states this (or the actual definition if I am wrong). So, what is a simplicial graph?

Comment: From the references I could find that mention simplicial graphs, this seems to be a synonym for simple graphs (no loop, no multi-edges) if we talk about a simplicial graph without any reference to a given simplicial complex. We can also talk about the simplicial graph of a given simplicial complex.

Comment: @Caduk I looked up simple graphs and I think you are correct. The nlab page for "graph" mentions explicitly that simple graph is synonymous with simplicial graph. Since you pointed me to simple graphs, if you want to post this as an answer, I'll accept it.